# Geometry nodes point instance sort

Tags: geometry-nodes

In **Geometric Node -> Point Instance**, currently I can only randomly control the arrangement order through **seed**.

Can I arrange it in order（1、2、3、4、5、6）?

Thank you for your help:)

[image]

Comment: i don't think you can do this at the moment only with geometry nodes. Of course you can, but not with collection, but just manually with 9 different point instances OR...just increase seed that often until it matches...(sorry, couldn't resist) 

Comment: @Chris It's really hard, thank you for your reply:)

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer" so that this question will not continue to be displayed as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for *Blender 3+* is the following:

- Use the node `Collection Info` and `Instance on Points`.
- Activate the option *Separate Children* for `Collection Info` and the option *Pick Instances* for `Instance on Points`.

This way the index of the current point is used for the instantiation of the objects from your collection.

If you do this as in your example with a grid, where the points are numbered in rows, you would have to rotate the grid by $90°$ first.

[image]