# 2 objects to instance on points? Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

New to geometry nodes.

Trying to get two objects to instance on a mesh circle with an alternating pattern. For example, (the red circles indicate a different shape in the picture). I tried using collection info but the whole collection gets instanced on each point (makes sense). Having trouble finding a tutorial on this for some reason. What kind of math do I need to solve to make this happen? Thank you :)

[image]

Comment: If you have two different objects in your collection: Activate *Separate Children* in the node `Collection Info` and *Pick Instance* in the node `Instance on Points`. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/235498/